# Open file using integrated WSL terminal in the same window VS code

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the integrated terminal to open a file in VS code.  The file keeps opening in a new window instead of the same instance.  I have all the window settings set to open in a new tab in the same instance, it's only behaving this way when I try to open the file via the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -r option:

```
$ code -r your.file
```

Got it from the --help of code:

```
$ code --help
code 1.61.0

Usage: code [options][paths...]

To read from stdin, append '-' (e.g. 'ps aux | grep code | code -')

Options
  -d --diff <file> <file>           Compare two files with each other.
  -a --add <folder>                 Add folder(s) to the last active window.
  -g --goto <file:line[:character]> Open a file at the path on the specified line and character position.
  -n --new-window                   Force to open a new window.
  -r --reuse-window                 Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.
  -w --wait                         Wait for the files to be closed before returning.
  -h --help                         Print usage.

Extensions Management
  --list-extensions                                           List the installed extensions.
  --show-versions                                             Show versions of installed extensions, when using --list-extensions.
  --category <category>                                       Filters installed extensions by provided category, when using --list-extensions.
  --install-extension <extension-id[@version] | path-to-vsix> Installs or updates the extension. The identifier of an extension is always
                                                          
`${publisher}.${name}`. Use `--force` argument to update to latest version. To install a specific version provide `@${version}`. For example: 'vscode.csharp@1.2.3'.
  --uninstall-extension <extension-id>                        Uninstalls an extension.

Troubleshooting
  -v --version Print version.
  -s --status  Print process usage and diagnostics information.
```